# WebApp becomes unresponsive after initiating Remote desktop Connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, rdp

My becomes unresponsive after creating a batch file and calling mstc to execute a remote desktop connection. I would have thought that this is an independent process and does not rely in any way to my python scrypt.

```
import os


def rdp_session(server, user, temporary_pass):
    """create Batch file to create .bat file that initiates rdp with variables"""
    rdp = open("rdp_test.bat", "w")
    rdp.write("cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/"+server+" /user:"+user+" /pass:"+temporary_pass+"\n")
    rdp.write("mstsc /v:"+server+" /admin")
    rdp.close()
    os.system("rdp_test.bat")
    #os.remove("rdp_test.bat") optional, to delete file with creds after executing
```

I also tried using:

```
subprocess.call("rdp_test.bat")
subprocess.Popen(["rdp_test.bat"])   #doesnt initiate my rdp
```

I get the same result.

Why does this happen and what can I do so my stays responsive while my RDP runs?

To add a bit of context, I have this function within a Flask App, which I use to remote connect to different machines. when 1 rdp, the web app does not respond to any commands, and when I terminate my rdp, everything I clicked on suddenly executes.

Comment: spawn a different process?

Comment: I see, reading...https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit on subprocesses, I managed find that none of these options were immediately effective since I needed to not only run a subprocess with Popen but additionally needed to use [Pathname expansion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

from which I ended up doing:

```
subprocess.Popen([os.path.expanduser("My_File.bat")])
```

> expanduser will expand a pathname that uses ~ to represent the current
>   user's home directory. This works on any platform where users have a
>   home directory, like Windows, UNIX, and Mac OS X; it has no effect on
>   Mac OS.

Otherwise my app would run all subsequent commands after closing my rdp session. This allows me to run multiple sub-processes independently from my web app and allows it to be responsive at the same time

Answer (score 0):

In order for your session to continue you need to spawn another process, independent of the one that will terminate immediately after executing your script.